# How to safe encode a random byte array into textual format

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

Mongo Change Stream is retuned in a binary format

To be able to script a mongo change stream I want to encode the byte array into a format that would be command line parameter safe.

```
pprint.pprint(change['_id']['_data'])
(b'\x82[8\x92G\x00\x00\x00\x01Fd_id\x00d[8\x91\xf2.\xc2\xd4\x00\x0b\xabO\x98'
 b'\x00Z\x10\x04\x16,\x92\xf8\xbf\x92G\x87\x8d1\xff(\x1a\x1b{\xc8\x04')
```

What would be a safe format to convert the binary array text that would be accepted as a parameter?

Example for conversion from binary to given format, and from given format input str() back into binary would be helpful.

### Attempt 1

```
base64.b85encode(change['_id']['_data']).decode('ascii')
'f?GI}M*si-0Y+qBX=DIoTR4&OF2d9R3#(6<09p_P7A%tZzmi9XjWPcy8XJ4a1O'
```

Going from binary to base85 works, but I can't seem to figure the way back.

---

**EDIT: Reopening Rational**

I think this question should not be marked as duplicate as this question targets conversion of random byte arrays which do not represent a human readable character / encoding. As follows the previous question focuses on converting a string into binary array and back, which is a **special case** of binary to string representation while my use case calls for a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh cool, I think I've figured it out

`base64.b85decode` will take string as well as binary as input.

Example:

```
b = b'\x82[8\x929\x00\x00\x00\x04Fd'
b == base64.b85decode(base64.b85encode(b).decode('ascii'))
True
```

Comment: Yet this is not base64; *Going from binary to base64 works, but I can't seem to figure the way back*, you go back the same way, but with `base54.b64decode()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters true, I've edited the post to say base85. Thank you for the comment.